# How to get/modify all user sessions from a Spring @Service bean (using Struts mvc)?

Tags: java, spring, session, struts

I am implementing a notification service that notifies all users (with active sessions) about new notifications. Since this web application uses Struts MVC (not a single page application), the use of the Web Socket didn't seem appropriate as every page load would require a new WS connection. Instead, my approach was to run a Spring @Service every minute to update all the active users session with a "Unread_Notification_Count" so each page load could simply check the user's session for this value and change the display accordingly (eliminating a database query for every page load).

I have 2 questions: 1) Is this the best approach to solve this problem as I've read in the Spring docs that you should avoid changing users sessions directly. 
 2) If this approach is "ok", then how do I access each users session to insert/change the "Unread_Notification_Count" value?

```
@Service("notifySessionsService")
public class NotifySessionsServiceImpl implements NotifySessionsService {

    @Autowired
    private transient SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

    @Override
    public void updateUnReadNotificationCount() {

        for (Object principal : sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()) {
            List<SessionInformation> sessionInformationList = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(principal, false);
            for (SessionInformation sessionInformation : sessionInformationList) {
                System.out.println("Updating session for user: "  + ((User)principal).getUsername() + ", sessionId: " + sessionInformation.getSessionId());
                // [Get users notification count here]
                // [Put in session, e.g. session.put("Unread_Notification_Count", count)]
            }
        }

    }

    public void setSessionRegistry(SessionRegistry sessionRegistry) {
        this.sessionRegistry = sessionRegistry;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try a POC to ensure Spring's `SessionRegistry` is aware of sessions created external to Spring?  But assuming that does work, having an active session doesn't mean the user is active.  The user may have closed the client and the session is just waiting to timeout.  To avoid a db hit during page load consider a regularly scheduled AJAX call from the client to get just its own count.

Comment: Also, I don't see anything in the `SessionRegistry` API to access the session to be able to set an attribute.

Comment: I don't either - hence my question ;-)

Comment: The ajax call could be an option - just have a piece of code on every page to hit the db every 5 minutes or so.  Makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew thanks for the idea.  I ended up choosing the javascript/client pull version.  Just for closure my code ended up like the code below.  The client checks for notifications every 5 minutes (based off the clock - not a timer)

```
var queryNotificationsEvery = 5; // in minutes

function startNotificationService(appUserId) {
    // Check each minute to see if we need to query for notifications
    setInterval(queryNotificationCount, 1000 * 60, appUserId)
}

function queryNotificationCount(appUserId) {

    var currentMinute = new Date().getMinutes();
    if (currentMinute % queryNotificationsEvery === 0) {

        // Query server via AJAX
        var notificationCount = queryServer(appUserId);

        // Change UI
        changeUINotifications(notificationCount);
    }

}
```